# Erro ao inicializar app criado com ionic 4

Tags: ionic3

Olá iniciei um app com ionic 4 pela CLI, o básico mesmo.

**Comandos utilizados:**

==> $ ionic start app-build blank --type=angular

==> $ cd app-build

==> $ ionic cordova platform add android

==> $ ionic cordova build android

Até ai tudo bem! Levanto o app com o comando **$ ionic serve** para ver se existe algum erro de JavaScript e de boas não tem.

Transfiro o app para o meu dispositivo: **Moto G1 | Android 4.4.4** e faço a instalação. Quando executo o app abre uma caixa de diálogo com o titulo: **Application Error** e com seguinte erro: **net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED(http://localhost:8080/)**

**OBS: Testei em um aparelho: Samsung J5 | Android 6.0.0 e funcionou de boas!**

Agora não sei se pode ser problemas de versão do Android se poderem me ajudar ficarei grato.

Comment: Como você transferiu para o seu dispositivo? Ionic Dev App, ionic cordova run android ou instalou o apk? Obs.: Para as versões mais antigas do Android é necessário instalar o plugin crosswalk-webview. `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview`.

Comment: Por um acaso, você não está fazendo nenhuma requisição http para localhost:8080? Se estiver, não vai funcionar mesmo, por que o teu server não vai estar no localhost e sim no computador.

Comment: @Renata no Ionic Dev App funcionando normal, com **$ ionic cordova run android** não estou conseguindo executar desta maneira porque meu aparelho não aparece conectado para subir o app, sim eu testei instalando o apk direto no aparelho. E vc disse desse plugin `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview` adicionei ele e depois rodei `$ ionic cordova build android` e deu erro na hora da compilação.

Comment: @LucasBrogni não estou fazendo nenhuma requisição, o app está enxuto, criei do zero não adicionei nada. Criei  e compilei para testar e não rodou, mas creio que seja algo da versão do Android porque em uma versão maior, como eu disse acima no post funcionou. :(

Comment: Inclua no config.xml o seguinte: `<allow-navigation href="http://localhost:8080/*"/>`, para garantir a permissão ao localhost.

Comment: Qual foi o erro na compilação após incluir o crosswalk-webview?

Comment: Ok. Vou tentar adicionar essa configuração e já te respondo e também te mandarei o erro que deu.

Comment: @Renata você queria saber quais os erros que deram quando instalei o plugin que você mandou, segue o link com os prints do erros [https://imgur.com/a/BHUN55z](https://imgur.com/a/BHUN55z)

Comment: @Bruno Henrique esse erro provavelmente ocorreu devido à incompatibilidade de dependências. Você pode incluir no `build.gradle` o seguinte código: `configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    }
}`

Comment: @Renata coloquei a configuração citada no arquivo `build.gradle` e fiz o build usando o comando `$ ionic cordova build android` e ainda continua o erro :(